# How to use Navigator.of(context) inside parent widget's callback function?

Tags: flutter

I am rather new to Flutter but I am coming from Angular background. In Angular, you oftentimes use the Parent/Child component pattern when rendering components. In such a scenario you would have the parent component respond to events emitted by the child component and then perform some logic. For example, you could have a parent component called `Dashboard` and inside the dashboard, you can have a button component. This button component would then emit an event when it was clicked. The parent would listen for this event and react when a new event is emitted, for example, change routes.

My understanding is that Flutter has a similar concept in such that you can handle your logic inside the parent 'widget'. What I was attempting to achieve was to have a parent widget let's call it `LandingPage` this widget would then render two button widgets and I wanted to pass down callback functions to the button widgets and change routes in the parent when they were pressed. I extracted the button widgets into my app-specific widgets to remove code duplication as such:

`primary-button.dart`:

```
class PrimaryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  PrimaryButton({@required this.buttonText, this.onPressedCallback ,this.width: 300.0});  
  final String buttonText;
  final double width;
  final VoidCallback onPressedCallback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      child: RaisedButton(
        elevation: 8.0,
        onPressed: () => this.onPressedCallback,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: ... (removed for brevity)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For the `primary-button.dart` widget I wish to pass in any callback function that returns void (analogous angular's event emitter). As shown in the code above.

In the parent component I then have the following:
`landing-page.dart`

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {

void onLoadHomePage(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.of(context).push(...)
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(...
   PrimaryButton(buttonText: "Hello world", onPressedCallback: this.onLoadHomePage(context))
  );
 }

}
```

The above of course doesn't work because the primary-button isn't ready to accept a callback with a context in its callback signature, plus `Navigator.of(context)` is expecting context to be used. Passing the `BuildContext` feels like this is the wrong way of doing, and even if I have to pass `BuildContext` between parent and child widget I have not been able to get this working. This seems reasonable right? Or is this wrong way of thinking about these stateless widgets.

If I just copy the contents of `primary-button.dart` into the `landing-page.dart` widget and inside `onPressed` callback use `Navigator.of(context)` everything works as expected. But feel like I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not misunderstanding, the mainly problem is how to make the `onPressedCallback` function work.

I think you don't need to transmit the `context` parameter, try this:

```dart
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...
      PrimaryButton(
        buttonText: "Hello world",
        onPressedCallback: () {
          this.onLoadHomePage(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then `onLoadHomePage` function can access the `context` parameter itself.

Comment: But then the primary button widget is isn’t really reusable. When pressed it will always execute ‘onLoadHoePage’. Plus how are you able to access ‘this.onLoadHomePage’ if the ‘primary-button’ widget is supposed to be in a separate dart file, to be reusable. Does that make sense? Thanks for replying

Comment: Why is not reusable? My code here is in the `LandingPage` class, pass `() { this.onLoadHomePage(context); }` to the `PrimaryButton` class. If you wanna use PrimaryButton in other places, just pass in another callback function as you need. I will edit my answer to be more clearly.

Comment: oh I see what you mean now. Hmm, that actually is what I was looking for. I will test this evening and if it works I will accept the answer. Thanks alot!